# Data still appear after get deleted

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im new at react native, i hane an issue to delete data. I got the data from this.props.getAllRouteSchedules. After i delete the data, the data still appear, i have to go back to previos screen and back again to the screen to make it gone. I tried to call the screen again after click delete, and it work the data gone, but if i delete 3 data i have to back 3 times to exit the screen. Im confuse how to make the screen dismiss after i press back.

This is my code :

```
confirmDelete = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Delete RouteSchedule?',
      'Are you sure you want to delete the RouteSchedule?',
      [
        { text: 'Cancel', style: 'cancel' },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          onPress: () => {

            deleteScheduleScreen(this.props.deleteRouteSchedule(this.state.selectedId))


          }
        }
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    )
  }
```

this is the render part :

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonAgree} onPress={() => {
                          this.confirmDelete();
                          this.setModalVisible();
                          }}>
                      <Text style={styles.buttonTextAgree}>Agree</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: try this once async() => {

            await deleteScheduleScreen(this.props.deleteRouteSchedule(this.state.selectedId))

Comment: could you share your `deleteScheduleScreen(this.props.deleteRouteSchedule(this.state.selectedId)` function and how you store you data?

Answer (score 0):

Store all data which you get from `this.props.getAllRouteSchedules` to `state` . Then if you update the state it will render automatically . Then you don't need to go and back between screen .